# Avi file compression

Tags: c#, .net, compression, avi

Im writing a .Net application, which joins bitmap files into .avi video file. To do that im using [AVIFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) api. Everything went fine until i've got to the point where i needed to compress resulting video. I've found a method [AVISaveOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756816%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which shows a dialog, where user can select an appropriate codec and its settings. However, the problem is - i dont want this dialog, neither do i need those advanced settings. I do need a codec selection somewhere on my UserControl tho. So my questions are basically:

1) Is there a way to get the list of availible video codecs installed on the machine?

2) Is there a way to load default settings for selected codec? (so i can initialize [AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756791%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with those values)

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, i guess. I ended up using FFMPEG (via AForge.Net wrapper)